# Pip3.7.exe Doesn't Accept --python param from Pycharm

Tags: python, pip, pycharm

I'm trying to create a new interpreter in Pycharm but when I hit the create button Pycharm is running pip with a --python param that pip doesn't like. Any advice?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to create a `pipenv` environment with `pip` selected as a `pipenv` executable. These are different things. Either switch to a pure virtual environment or select a correct `pipenv` executable to proceed without an error.